# var keyword runtime or compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, variables

var keyword gets the type at the runtime or compile time?

or depends?

Comment: This has been discussed at other questions, including [C# 'var' vs specific type performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356846/c-var-vs-specific-type-performance) and [
What's the difference between dynamic(C# 4) and var?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var).

Comment: it doesnt show up in the suggestions dude. implement a better algorithm for that. i m not telephatic.

Comment: And I'm not a SO developer, plus I didn't vote to close.  I added the links so people could go there for more info.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555625/var-reference-in-c-is-boxing/3555656#3555656

Comment: See [var-reference-in-c-sharp-is-boxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555625/var-reference-in-c-sharp-is-boxing)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Plain and simple: compile time

`var` isn't a type. The actual type is figured out at compile-time.

`var` variables are also known as [Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

Comment: i ve been trying to come up with a case that type wont be known until runtime, is that possible?

Comment: @user, no.  If the compiler can't determine the type, compilation will fail.

Comment: You should check the new `dynamic` keyword in C# 4.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi, the Type is known by the compiler, even in the case of the dynamic Type.  The compiler is merely unaware of the capabilities of any particular instance of the dynamic Type.

Answer (score 4):

var type gets at `compile time` .

Var is an implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: If you're going to add quotes from the MSDN page, you might as well link to it.

Answer (score 1):

The [var keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is implicitly typed.  This means that it is strongly typed, but the compiler determines the type.