# Difference in declaration: "var x = .." vs "var x; x = .."

Tags: c#, variables

I am new to C#, please help me to understand the difference between the below statement:

```
var variable_name = new class_a(); // there is no error and is working fine

var variable_name; 
variable_name = new class_a(); // this line is throwing error
```

when I rewrote the statement as

```
class_a variable_name; 
variable_name = new class_a(); // this is working fine
```

Comment: [var keyword runtime or compile time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632918/var-keyword-runtime-or-compile-time) might help you understand this.

Comment: Just to add to the existing answers. "var" has an alternative the "dynamic" and it's type is resolved dynamically at runtime. If you try your second line with dynamic keyword it will work fine. However dynamic type somewhat reduces  the visibility of your code and don't allow intellisense autocompletion.

Answer (score 7):

`var` is used to introduce an [implicitly typed local variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx). The type is known at compile time and is inferred from the type of the expression on the right hand side of the initialization statement. Using your example:

```
var variable_name = new class_a();
```

the compiler infers that `new class_a()` is an expression that yields an object of type `class_a`. Hence `variable_name` is declared as being of type `class_a`. This code is completely equivalent to

```
class_a variable_name = new class_a();
```

If the right hand side of the initialization is omitted, then there is no way for the compiler to infer the type. Hence the compilation error.

Answer (score 5):

`var` automatically *infers* the data type based on the *value* that the variable is initialized with.

```
var i = 3;    // 3 is an int; thus, i is declared as an int.
```

In your second example, there is no value specified, thus, inference is not possible.

```
var i;        // no data type can be inferred
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use `var` you don't specify the `datatype`, so you should assign some value for it so that the `var` 'variable' becomes of that `datatype`.

Only declaring and not assigning will not help and will throw an error in case of `var`.

Hope it clears your doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Because `var` infers the type and is evaluated to a statically typed declaration at compile time, for example:

```
var var_name; // The compiler does not know what type var is. It has not been inferred. Error!

var var_name = new class_a(); // The compiler knows var has been inferred as class_a();
```

which equates to...

```
class_a var_name = new class_a();
```

Download [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), compile your code, reflect it using ILSpy, and see what happens to your `var` declarations.

Comment: +1 for *compile time*, which no one else seems to of mentioned

Answer (score 0):

compiler wants to know the type of the variable when allocating a chunk of memory for it. the 3rd line do it and then gave it a value. the first line is ok because it's on one line and compiler knows the variable should be of type of `class_a` and it will allocate a memory and give the value of `new class_a()` object at the same time!
but the second one gives you error is because it will allocate a memory of no type! and you can't put any object of any type in that specific memory!